# Developing Unity Dash Plugins

Tags: unity-dash, plugins, search, documentation

I would like to develop a Unity dash plugin, but I can't find developer resources for building dash plugins. Can anyone direct me to online documentation or tutorials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should look around [here](http://developer.ubuntu.com/scopes/tutorial/). You can find there the API, examples and the cookbook.